# How can the speech to text function be integrated with an application?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I want to make a simple game which has a function of PICK, LEFT, Right and stop.

My problem is I want to make those functions of the game into a voice recognition using the speech to text function of android. I'm using eclipse as my IDE, I want to know how to integrate it with an application.

Hope you can give me a sample, it'll be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent i = new Intent(
                        RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Say the command!");
                startActivityForResult(i, 10);
```

Then add on activity result.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 10 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<String> s = data
                .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

//Do whatever you want with the data here.      
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you need two things.

1. Run the speech recognizer in the background so there is no annoying dialog interfering with the game
2. Recognize your target words reliably

For #1. You'll need [SpeechRecognizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) and a loop to run it, such as the one that uses [this](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/library/src/root/gast/speech/activation/WordActivator.java), or I guess you could use the dialog version. Either way start off using [this abstract class](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/library/src/root/gast/speech/SpeechRecognizingAndSpeakingActivity.java) to give you a head start.

For #2, you have to do some testing. Download the [Android Sensor Playground](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=root.gast.playground&hl=en) app to see if the recognizer can reliably recognize your words. If that is true, just use a simple `Sting<Set>` to match any recognition results. (or you could use [this handy class](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/library/src/root/gast/speech/text/match/WordMatcher.java)) If the recognizer is giving you trouble on certain words, then you need some stemming or phonetic matching. See [this class](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/library/src/root/gast/speech/text/match/SoundsLikeWordMatcher.java).